# Связка grafana+prometeus присылает в телеграм alerts с диграмами, но не отображает

Tags: grafana

Связка grafana+prometeus присылает в телеграм alerts с диграмами, но не отображает.
Просит поставить плагин grafana_image_render, после установки плагина делаю рестарт сервисов графаны и показывает ошибку в статусе
lvl=eror msg="Failed to read plugin provisioning files from directory" logger=provisioning.plugins path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins error="open /etc/grafana/provisioning/plugins: no such file or directory"
Can't read alert notification provisioning files from directory" logger=provisioning.notifiers path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers error="open /etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers: no such file or directory

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не понятно что это за файл такой и почему он не устанавливается при установке плагина